# Using add-hoc angular directive in an external html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This should be simple but I can't get it done right.
I have some custom angular directives working just fine, and I'm intended to use some in a external (other domain/server/port) html.

First, I included scripts from the working directives webapp:

```
<script 
    data-main="http://localhost:9000/vassets/javascripts/main.js"
    src="http://localhost:9000/vassets/lib/requirejs/require.js">
</script>
```

Then I just tried to use one of them in the external html:

```
<div custom-directive attrib="abcd"></div>
```

Problem is template associated with directive cant be loaded, since it is declared as:

```
templateUrl: '/vassets/partials/customDirective.html'
```

And of course can't be found when external html is loaded. 
There are alse issues regarding cross site.

It is clear that I'm not including external directives (and importing its source) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One thing which can be done is in the directives, instead of referencing to an external template, you can place the template inside the directive itself. Like:

```
template: '<div>Template here</div>'
```

Now when you export your directive file to a new app you will have no worries in exporting its template file as well.

Alternatively, you can keep your existing scenario and place the template in the location where the directive is looking for it.

Comment: The problem with html template approach is a dirty source code, since template is not as simple as a div, but a complete html with many elements

Comment: hmmm, then perhaps for dev environments one can have the templateUrl, but when building the project, one can replace the templateUrl with template and insert the html inside the directive. This will keep things clean when doing development and only bring in the dirty source code when going into production.

If not this then you'll need to place your template where the directive is looking for it. (as stated in the last line of my answer)